# Getting Unauthorized error when creating a project from template through API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-construction-cloud

I am trying to create an ACC project from a template through the API listed here (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/construction/admin/v1/accounts/:account_id/projects).

My Payload:
{
"name": "Project from template An 1",
"type": "Hospital",
"template": {
"projectId": "swdsdsd"
}
}

Response:
" {
"status": 401,
"type": "",
"id": "01c1fc75774a4c5b",
"title": "Unauthorized",
"detail": "Unauthorized"
}.
I am account admin and I am able to create a project through the API just fine. I am able to create a project through template from UI without error. I am not sure why am I getting "Unauthorized" error on this.

I tried updating my permission. I am account admin. I have access to the template. I am Project admin for this template.

Comment: A quick check, are you using 2LO or 3LO to call the POST Project API? Are you able to Get the projects by API?

Comment: Hi Zhong

Yes I am able to call the get Projects and Post Projects without issue. We are using 2LO

Comment: For POST Project endpoint, unlike the GET Projects endpoint, it requires User-Id in the header for 2LO as https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/admin-accounts-accountidprojects-POST/, did you forget to include that?